# Attach JavaScript to page with Commerce Events

Tags: commerce, 9

I'm using `hook_page_attachments_alter` in Drupal 9 to add some JavaScript dataLayer calls to certain routes, but I also need to add some to certain cart events (i.e. add item to cart).

I've written a CartEventSubscriber that listens for cart events and have one responding to the AddToCart event, but the only variable it exposes is `CartEntityAddEvent $event`.

Is there another way to tell from `hook_page_attachments_alter` or some other hook that I'm on a page that resulted from the Add to Cart click so that I can add this JS there?

Thanks!

Comment: You would attach the file to something on the page - a form, a node, or some other object. If it's a form, you can use hook_form_alter(), and attach your library with the `#attached` key of the form render array.

Comment: But how do I know it's only AFTER the item has been added to the cart? There is the Add To Cart form I could attach it to and I tried that form's `isSubmitted()` method, but it is always false due to the way that form redirects back to the page, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the [GA Push](https://www.drupal.org/project/ga_push) module, but it wasn't sure how fully it was being maintained, but I may revisit it in the future. But for my purposes for now, I just took inspiration from the way they use session objects. So, my AddToCart method ended up looking like ...

```
public function addToCart(CartEntityAddEvent $event) {
  /** @var \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariationInterface $product_variation */
  $product_variation = $event->getEntity();
  $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
  $session = null;
  if($request->hasSession()){
    $session = $request->getSession();
  }
  if(is_null($session)){
    return;
  }
  $session->set('{session_id}}', {js_snippet});
}
```

And in my .module file's hook_page_attachments_alter function, I added ...

```
if(\Drupal::request()->hasSession()){
  $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
  attachments[] = $session->get('{session_id}');
  $session->remove('{session_id}');
}
```

And proceeded to attach the snippets as normal.